# Jquery - Slide up when next element is clicked...when only on a different row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a click function that makes a div slide down.....when i click on the next li i want the previous div to slide back up and the new div to slide down but only when its on a different row....when its on the same row I'm going to put content in the div that i want to fadeIn

heres the fiddle im working with

http://jsfiddle.net/abtPH/3/

heres my jQuery

```
$('li').on('click', function(e){
  $(this).find('.outer').slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('active', 400);
});
```

heres my html

```
 <ul style="list-style: none;">
   <li>
    <div style="width: 156px; height: 156px; border: solid #cfcfcf 1px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; color: #cfcfcf;"> 156px X 156px</div>

  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>   
  </div>
  </li>  
<li>
<div style="width: 156px; height: 156px; border: solid #cfcfcf 1px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; color: #cfcfcf;"> 156px X 156px</div>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>   
</div>
</li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: Why are you passing `400` to the `toggleClass` method?

Comment: Because that's the default value for slideToggle (and provides animation)

Comment: Try learning how accordion works,i think its similar

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall The second parameter should be a boolean value, a truthy value adds the class and falsy value removes it.

Comment: @undefined http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/ default _duration_ of slideToggle, my apologies.

Comment: jqueryui isn't even mentioned in this post or as a tag.  It's a good idea to include all the appropriate tags in a post.

Comment: I'll add it as I answered his initial question on this setup...

Comment: You haven't defined what the expected behavior is when someone clicks a second li as the first is animating. Are you looking for something more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/X8Vgr/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you're looking for something like this?

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li:not(li.active + li)', function (e) {
    function toggle(el) {
        el.toggleClass('active', 400);
        el.find('.outer').slideToggle();
    }
    var me = $(this)
    if(me.parent().has(':animated').length == 0) {
        toggle(me.siblings('.active').andSelf());
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B6TZS/

Comment: Quickly click the 00 and the 10 (the one below it). Is that expected? (I confess didn't read the question.)

Comment: @acdcjunior What happens when you do that? Maybe I'm not clicking fast enough, but I didn't notice anything.

Comment: @acdcjunior Ah, I think I see what you're talking about. That would be the fact that the active class isn't toggled until after the element has finished sliding up or down (400ms later). If you click another element in the meantime, it doesn't register the currently animating element as an instance of `.active`.

Comment: @user1502223 Do you want for the second one to not expand until the first one has finished?

Comment: @Asad - yeah that would be ideal.....so the second div will not show up until the first one has finished......i also want it so that if the div with the class outer is shown and the user clicks on the next box..it wont slideup.....i only want it to slide up if the user clicks on a differnt row

Comment: @user1502223 Please edit those details into your question. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Asad - hmm if you click on the first box......then the second...the second one does not work.....if you click on the third...then the second again it works though

Comment: @user1502223 Should the first row not work when the second row is expanded?

Comment: @user1502223 Also, should both the first and second column work or just the first one?

Comment: @Asad - notice how when you click on the box thats next to each other it does not slide up then down then change content.....it just fades in really nicely

Comment: @user1502223 Something like this, then? http://jsfiddle.net/Ayc9t/ If any li is selected in a row, none of the other lis in that row should respond.

Comment: @Asad - no im sorry if i wasent clear....if you click on the box next to the one that is open it should still open up but not slide up then down it should just fade in nicely.....check out the example on http://ro3.us/work.html  ...it should work like that....thanks for you help btw

Comment: @user1502223 That wasn't actually part of your question. I'm not going to make an entire website for you. What you asked for originally was just this functionality: "when i click on the next li i want the previous div to slide back up and the new div to slide down", and I've already gone well past that.